# What is wrong with this lambda expression in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda, list-comprehension

Say I want to get a list of functions that returns `x * 0`, `x * 1`, ..., `x * 9` (`x` is the input variable). I am using a lambda expression in a list comprehension. Below is my code with `x = 1`:

```
x = 1
funcs = [lambda x: x * i for i in range(10)]
res = [f(x) for f in funcs]
print(res)
```

However, I am getting

```
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

The expected result should be

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What is wrong with my code and how should I fix it?

Comment: following the linked duplicate post: `funcs = [lambda x, i=i: x * i for i in range(10)]`.

Comment: `lambda x: x * i` has a free variable, `i`. When you *call the function*, `i` is equal to `9`, the last value it was assigned to in the list comprehension.

Comment: The "principled" way of doing this is to create a factory function, e.g. `def makefunc(i): return lambda x: x*i` then in your comprehension, `[makefunc(i) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: Just for completeness, the `lamba x, i=i:` technique is called "capturing" the current value of i.